# Logout and redirect WordPress user id without he refresh the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I m developing a functionality triggered on a button $('.disconnect-classroom-button') when click, I logout all members inside that group, and the logout is done successfully ( but the user has to click or refresh the page to take effect even I use ajax ), this is not the result I want :
here is the php callback functions :

```
// PHP function to send students_ids
function send_students_ids() {
    if (isset($_POST['payload']) && $_POST['payload'] == 'disconnect_classroom') {
        // Verify nonce
        check_ajax_referer('kwf_nonce', 'security');

        $group_type = bp_groups_get_group_type(bp_get_current_group_id());

        $students_ids = array();

        $group_members = groups_get_group_members(array(
            'group_id'            => bp_get_current_group_id(),
            'exclude_admins_mods' => true,
            'exclude_banned'      => true,
            'exclude'             => false,
            'group_role'          => array('member'),
            'search_terms'        => false,
        ));

        foreach ($group_members['members'] as $member) {
            $students_ids[] = $member->ID;
        }

        // Send students_ids to the JavaScript function
        wp_send_json_success(array('students_ids' => $students_ids));
    }
}

// Add the custom action hook to the wp_ajax_ hook
add_action('wp_ajax_send_students_ids', 'send_students_ids');

// PHP function to process logout using students_ids
function kwf_ajax_logout_group() {

    if (isset($_POST['payload']) && $_POST['payload'] == 'disconnect_classroom') {
        // Verify nonce
        check_ajax_referer('kwf_nonce', 'security');

        // Get the user IDs from the POST data
        $user_ids = $_POST['user_ids'];

        // Loop through the user IDs and log them out
        foreach ($user_ids as $user_id) {

            if (is_user_logged_in($user_id)) {
                // Get all sessions for the user with ID $user_id
                $sessions = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance($user_id);
        
                // We have got the sessions, destroy them all!
                $sessions->destroy_all();
            }

        }

        // Send a success response
        wp_send_json_success(array(
            'message' => 'You will be logged out.',
            'user_ids' => $user_ids,
            'redirect_url' => home_url(), // Set the redirection URL
        ));


        // Redirect to the homepage after logging out
        
       // exit; 
    }
}
```

and here is the event handler in ajax :
( **enqueued only for single group pages** ):

```
if(function_exists('bp_is_groups_component') && bp_is_groups_component()) { // single group
 wp_enqueue_script( 'kwf-bp-groups-js', KWF_JS_PATH . 'bp-groups.js', array( 'jquery' ), KWF_THEME_VERSION, true );}
```

```
    $('.disconnect-classroom-button').hover(
        function () {
            // Hover in: Change the icon to bb-icon-file-export with ease-in-out transition
            $(this).find('i').removeClass('bb-icon-file-import').addClass('bb-icon-file-export').css('transition', 'all 0.3s ease-in-out');
        },
        function () {
            // Hover out: Change the icon back to bb-icon-file-import with ease-in-out transition
            $(this).find('i').removeClass('bb-icon-file-export').addClass('bb-icon-file-import').css('transition', 'all 0.3s ease-in-out');
        }
    ).on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var button = $(this);
        var nonce = $(this).data('security');
    
        NProgress.start();
        NProgress.set(0.4);
    
        // Increment 
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            NProgress.inc();
        }, 1000);
    
        // Step 1: Send Member IDs
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: 'send_students_ids',
                payload: 'disconnect_classroom',
                security: nonce,
                send_members: true, // Add a flag to indicate sending member IDs
            },
            success: function (response) {
                // Check if sending member IDs was successful
                if (response.success) {
                    var memberIds = response.data.students_ids;
    
                    // Step 2: Process Logout
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: ajaxurl,
                        headers: {
                            pragma: "no-cache",
                            "cache-control": "no-cache"
                        },
                        data: {
                            action: 'kwf_ajax_logout_group',
                            payload: 'disconnect_classroom',
                            security: nonce,
                            user_ids: memberIds, // Include the member IDs for logout
                        },
                        success: function (logoutResponse) {
                            // Check if logout was successful
                            if (logoutResponse.success) {
                               
                                button.text(kwf_translate.disconnected_classroom);
                                NProgress.done();
                                clearInterval(interval);
    
                                // Step 3: Send Success Message
                                jQuery(document).trigger(
                                    'bb_trigger_toast_message',
                                    [
                                        '',
                                        '<div>' + kwf_translate.disconnected_message + '</div>',
                                        'info',
                                        null,
                                        true
                                    ]
                                );
                                 // Trigger custom event for successful logout
                                console.log(logoutResponse.data)
                                
                                 // Dispatch a custom event after successful logout
                                var logoutEvent = new CustomEvent('logoutSuccess', {
                                    detail: {
                                        message: 'You will be logged out.'
                                    }
                                });
                                window.dispatchEvent(logoutEvent);
                              

                                // Notify the user in their browser
                                 
                                    /* console.log(logoutResponse.data.redirect_url) */
                                /* setTimeout(() => {
                                    button.text(kwf_translate.disconnect_classroom);
                                }, 60000);  */               
                                                
                            } else {
                                // Handle logout failure
                                console.error('Logout failed:', logoutResponse.data);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            // Handle logout error
                            console.error('Logout error:', error);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    // Handle sending member IDs failure
                    console.error('Sending member IDs failed:', response.data);
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                // Handle sending member IDs error
                console.error('Sending member IDs error:', error);
            }
        });
    });
```

and there is global.js that I think I should use to process the logout

What I want : **Automatically log out the user with the $user_id and navigate them to the homepage, regardless of their current page. This should occur without the need for a page refresh or button click, and it should apply to the user with the $user_id, not the individual who clicked the button. **

Comment: If I got you right, there are X people within a class room, and as soon as the teacher clicks "Dismiss" all the users should be logged out. Your problem is, that the users are not logged out automatically?

Comment: Yes exactly. the users are not logged out automatically until they refresh the page or click on a button, then , they are redirected to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have two ways of achieving what you need

The first would be implementing websockets to allow for asynchronous two-way communication between server and client. I don't know what are the techniques to do so in PHP, but I'm sure they exist

Second would be implement good old-fashioned polling on the client side. Based on some interval send a HTTP request using AJAX asking server to tell if the user is still logged in or not. It's not the most elegant solution, but way easier and was utilized heavily when websockets were unavailable (not yet introduced or not yet widly supported by major browsers)